# Get Total Value of list in visualforcepage that using standardController

Tags: visualforce, javascript, standardcontroller

I want to make a vfp that have summary of total value like this:
this is several ways that i already tried:

1. update visualforcepage from standardController="Review_Summary__c" extensions="Revsum_RelatedListCtrl" to using controller="Revsum_RelatedListCtrl",
   But i got error You can't change the standard controller object Review_Summary__c because this page is referenced in the page layout RS Layout BC. Because i put this vfp in detail layout of review summary.
2. Tried to using javascript, but the value of totalDPLocalAmount and totalPayLocalAmount is null

what should i do to make it works? is there any ways to make it happend without create a new field in object review_summary?

this is my code now:

```
    <apex:page standardController="Review_Summary__c" extensions="Revsum_RelatedListCtrl">
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:form id="mainform">
        <apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!list_rsi}" var="i" width="100%">
                <apex:column value="{!i.Delivery_Request_ID__c}" headerValue="Delivery Request No" />
                <apex:column value="{!i.Customer_ID__c}" headerValue="Customer Name" headerClass="tc" />
                <apex:column value="{!i.Delivery_Order_ID__r.DP_Percent__c}" headerValue="DP %" />
                <apex:column value="{!i.Delivery_Order_ID__r.DP_Local_Amount__c}" headerValue="DP Amount" />
                <apex:column value="{!i.Delivery_Order_ID__r.DP_Payment_Term__c}" headerValue="DP Payment Term" />
                <apex:column value="{!i.Delivery_Order_ID__r.DP_Custom_Payment__c}" headerValue="DP Custom Payment" />
                <apex:column value="{!i.Delivery_Order_ID__r.DP_Grace_Month_Period__c}" headerValue="DP Grace Period (Months)" />
                <apex:column value="{!i.Delivery_Order_ID__r.DP_Classification__c}" headerValue="DP AR Classification" />
                <apex:column value="{!i.Delivery_Order_ID__r.Pay_Percent__c}" headerValue="PAY %" /> 
                <apex:column value="{!i.Delivery_Order_ID__r.Pay_Local_Amount__c}" headerValue="PAY Amount" />
                <apex:column value="{!i.Delivery_Order_ID__r.PAY_Payment_Term__c}" headerValue="PAY Payment Term" />
                <apex:column value="{!i.Delivery_Order_ID__r.PAY_Custom_Payment__c}" headerValue="PAY Custom Payment" />
                <apex:column value="{!i.Delivery_Order_ID__r.PAY_Grace_Period_Months__c}" headerValue="PAY Grace Period (Months)" />
                <apex:column value="{!i.Delivery_Order_ID__r.Pay_Classification__c}" headerValue="PAY AR Classification" />
                <apex:column value="{!i.Delivery_Order_ID__r.Bank_Leasing_Company__c}" />
                <apex:column value="{!i.Delivery_Order_ID__r.Leasing_Status__c}" />
                <apex:column value="{!i.Delivery_Order_ID__r.PO_Number__c}" />
                <apex:column value="{!i.Delivery_Order_ID__r.Leasing_TCompletion_Date__c}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" id="footerSection">
                <apex:outputText value="Total DP Amount: " />
                <apex:outputText value="" id="totalDPLocalAmount" />
                <apex:outputText value="Total Pay Amount: " />
                <apex:outputText value="" id="totalPayLocalAmount" />

            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
    
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var totalDPLocalAmount = 0;
        var totalPayLocalAmount = 0;
        
        // loop through each row in the page block table
        var tableRows = document.querySelectorAll('table[id$="_list_rsi"]').item(0).getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (var i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
            var dpAmount = parseFloat(tableRows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1].textContent);
            var payAmount = parseFloat(tableRows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[9].textContent);
            
            totalDPLocalAmount += isNaN(dpAmount) ? 0 : dpAmount;
            totalPayLocalAmount += isNaN(payAmount) ? 0 : payAmount;
        }
        
        // update the total DP and pay amounts in the page
        document.getElementById("totalDPLocalAmount").innerHTML = totalDPLocalAmount.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("totalPayLocalAmount").innerHTML = totalPayLocalAmount.toFixed(2);
    }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

[image]